# Missing console output after grub

Tags: centos, kernel, boot, grub, serial-console

I'm trying to boot CentOs already installed on an appliance.
This appliance has only two input connectors:

- 1 USB port, where I plugged in a USB hub, to which I connected a keyboard
- 1 Male 9 Pin Serial port / RS232

It also has 2 Gigabit Ethernet ports, one of which is used for remote administration with Intel BMC and Intel SOL (Serial-Over-LAN)

I'm connected to the server via the Intel SOL.

Now the problem:
when I boot the server, I successfully reach the Grub loader and I can select the entries, but after that, the output shows the `�` character, and nothing more happens,  whichever the entry I select.

I tried to boot from a live Centos image (using a USB Pendrive connected to the USB hub) but also, in this case, I can see the Grub loader, I can select the desired entry, but then it stuck with `�` character.

I also tried to:

- disable the `quiet` mode from the kernel flags
- add `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel lines
- add `console=tty0` `console=ttyS0` `console=tty1` `console=ttyS1` to the kernel lines
- in Grub Rescue mode, chain load and boot the `grubx64.efi` from the OS already installed and from the USB Pendrive

I'm honestly out of options now, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see if this solves your problem https://serverfault.com/a/713491/802321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `console=ttyS0,115200 console=ttyS1,115200` to the linux command and dropping `rhgb` solved the problem.